# Tasks with Mutex

Tags: vb.net, task, mutex

We have an operation which is very resource-intensive. I've been asked to make it synchronous, and to that end, found Mutex. It seems simple enough to implement, but I haven't yet succeeded. (This happens to live inside a console app, if that makes any difference-- though I can't imagine why it would.)  The sub startExecution is what I care about. I have some vars to store the task id, because I was having to restart my machine just to get the mutex to be unlocked (before I put in the Finally). I thought possibly I could kill the task using its process ID via the cmd line. It must be using something else for its PID, however, because a) the task ID is always something strangely low, like 2 or 4, and b) it doesn't show up in the tasklist. 
 So, to recap, two questions: 
 1. How may I kill whatever task is running? 
 2. Have I implemented the Mutex class correctly? 
 I've been flailing at this all day; if anyone has a clue I would be very grateful.

```
    Dim precrunchMutexName As String = "precrunchMutex"
    Dim precrunchMutex As Mutex

    Try
        precrunchMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(precrunchMutexName)
        'if successful, that means there's one in progress right now. 
    Catch ex As Exception
        'if one isn't found create a new one with that name
        precrunchMutex = New Mutex(False, precrunchMutexName)
    End Try

    Try
        Dim t As Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            Sub()
                writeLogClass.WriteLog("Waiting for mutex...")
                'request access to precrunch Mutex -- waitone
                If precrunchMutex.WaitOne() Then

                    writeLogClass.WriteLog("Mutex entered by task id: " & t.Id.ToString)

                    Try
                        startExecution()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        writeLogClass.WriteLog(ex.ToString())
                    Finally

                        'release Mutex to allow access to another thread 
                        precrunchMutex.ReleaseMutex()
                        writeLogClass.WriteLog("Mutex released")
                    End Try

                End If


            End Sub
        )
        Dim status = t.Status
        Dim currentId = t.Id
    Catch ex As Exception
        writeLogClass.WriteLog("Error occurred when starting task. " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: Why do you need mutex?

Comment: Because multiple of these processes peg the server and then our clients are hosed. Would semaphore be preferable..?

Comment: Why do you want to kill the task (you mean process, right)? Your scenario still does not make sense.

Comment: I want to kill it for debugging purposes. I've been changing things, and don't like having to restart my computer every time. In real life, when this program is in place, I won't want to kill it.

Comment: You are using mutex correctly. Operating system should release mutex if application crashes/gets killed. You can subscribe to Ctrl+C https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx in console and release the mutex before exiting prgram.